# Set Excel VLOOKUP to dynamic external file

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've built an excel file that runs a VLOOKUP with an external file. The external file changes daily, and the naming/location of the file is dynamically set without a standard convention. So I've put together a small VBA script lets the user select the day's file, then sets the file path and file name of the xls file to look up in the table_array.
However...
Populating a cell with this data and then trying to reference that cell in the VLOOKUP is returning an error ("A value is not available to the formula or function"). If I manually input the full filepath and filename into the cell running the VLOOKUP it works fine. It seems to not understand that the value being passed in from the other cell is a real file path.
Here is what I have:

```
B2 = fileName  (no dir path)
B3 = worksheetName
B4 = pathToFile
B5 = =CONCATENATE(B4&"["&B2&"]"&B3)
B7 = lookupValue
C7 = =VLOOKUP(B7,'B5'!$G:$I,3,FALSE)
```

C7 is obviously where I'm having the issue. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with the code you're trying, thanks.

Comment: @BigBen the formula in C7 is what is causing the error. the way it references B5 is not working

Comment: Hmm - a better approach might just be to update links.

Comment: You will need to use INDIRECT to return a valid range reference

Comment: @ScottCraner - can't remember, does INDIRECT work with closed workbooks?

Comment: Nope that is the one caveat.  there is no other way though, strictly with formula than INDIRECT.

Comment: Yeah - I would just update links here tbh.

Comment: @BigBen what do you mean by "update links"?

Comment: If you use the full filepath/filename in the formula, you have a link to that workbook. Excel allows you to update that link to a new workbook. The other option is to build the formula dynamically with the path/filename. *File* > *Edit Links to Files* > *Change Source* to update the link.

Comment: @jmarx34, you could extend your _small VBA script_ to update the links.  Have a look at `ThisWorkbook.LinkSources` and `ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink`.

Comment: @jmarx34 - almost any solution is better than INDIRECT (IMHO) - another alternative could be to use a Named Range that refers to the external file range and to use your small vba script to update the named range's RefersTo, and the use the Named Range in the VLOOKUP